# view data from temptable

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, temp-tables

I am having following query

```
select VendorNumber,stuff( (select distinct ','+dbo.vendordata.InvoiceStatus
                               from dbo.vendordata
                               where dbo.vendordata.VendorNumber = dbo.vendordata.VendorNumber 
                               for xml path('')
                              ), 1, 1, ''
                            ) as InvoiceStatus
    into #temp_table3
    from dbo.vendordata
    group by VendorNumber
```

I am using a temptable to store the result of invoice status and vendor number.when i use

```
select VendorNumber,InvoiceStatus  from #temp_table3
```

its throwing me an error

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
There is already an object named '#temp_table3' in the database.
```

How to view the data from temptable can any one help?

Comment: Drop the temp table first and then use the same query to create it.

Answer (score 2):

A temp tables and other local temporary objects are separated by session. Thus, if you don't terminate your session (close your query window in SSMS, disconnect, close the session, etc) the temp table will persist. If you run the script more than once so you will need to check if it already exists and drop it if it does (always a good idea to avoid issues like this).

```
-- do a check if temp table exists first then drop it before running

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_table3') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp_table3


select VendorNumber,stuff( (select distinct ','+dbo.vendordata.InvoiceStatus
                               from dbo.vendordata
                               where dbo.vendordata.VendorNumber = dbo.vendordata.VendorNumber 
                               for xml path('')
                              ), 1, 1, ''
                            ) as InvoiceStatus
into #temp_table3
from dbo.vendordata
group by VendorNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check Temp Table Exists or not in Temp DB with below Query

```
if exists (
select 1 from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects o
where o.xtype in ('U')  
and o.id = object_id(N'tempdb..#Tempdata')
)
DROP TABLE #Tempdata;
```